# Getting empty content response in scrapy when using it on amazon

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to scape amazon. But I kept getting empty response list. So tired to get the response as html page to view in browser to check it something is wrong.

To view the response in browser:

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

open_in_browser(response)
```

Here is page I got in response-

[image]

Also I did try with Google Bot as the user agent

`USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'`

And also tried middleware library scrapy-user-agents 0.1.1

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

The log : [pastebin.com/n4m2mmTf](https://pastebin.com/n4m2mmTf)

I could understand the problem if I got something like HTTP 503 or other error code but all I get is a page with empty content.

Tried it on other websites it worked.

Can anyone tell me what's causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Your IP is banned. Try to use proxies. You can check for empty response and retry the request

Comment: but I can visit this link

Comment: That's how amazon blocks you when you scrape them. Always use proxies and ensure you set a valid user agent.

Comment: I have used scrapy proxy tool and it tries a couple of proxies then says WARNING: No proxies available.

Comment: Other libraries requires manual proxy input which I don't have